# OpenGL - zNear and zFar Parameters

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I am trying to figure out what each parameter does. In the meantime I am playing around with glOrtho . I have already understood how everything works except zNear and zFar .

Comment: What research have you done already? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering

Comment: Youtube , Wikis , OpenGL forums , OpenGL FAQ , NeHe , Arcsynthesis.

Comment: @Zarkopafilis NeHe is outdated and shouldn't be used. NeHe teaches old OpenGL (OpenGL 2.0). However [Arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut) (modern OpenGL) tutorials are just fine.

Comment: In my article [LWJGL Tutorial Series - A Simple Moving Rectangle](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-tutorial-series-a-simple-moving-rectangle/30675/view.html) I discussed about `glOrtho` in `Creating an Orthographic Camera`

Comment: @AidanMueller I dont get it. I am trying to learn openGL for a month and there are so many tutorials.Shall I keep reading "The Red Book" and "The Superbible" or other stuff? It appears I am learning OpenGL 1.1 . Should I start learning 4.X or keep going?

Comment: @Zarkopafilis You basically want to make sure you are learning OpenGL 3+. Anything before version 3.0 is outdated. Things are done  very differently in modern OpenGL (OGL 3.0+). Legacy OpenGL uses a fixed function pipeline where you have no control over how the vertices are actually rendered, whereas in OGL 3+, you can write a mini program called a shader. Shaders basically allow you to program how the vertices are drawn to the screen. There are also many other differences, but that is the main difference. One more thing, some computers don't support some of the new versions of OGL 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the direction you are looking at, any vertices closer to you than znear will not be drawn, and any vertices that are farther than zfar will not be drawn.

If you are at origin, looking at +z direction, if there is a building with z coordinates 120, and your zfar is 100, than you won't see it.

Comment: So , would you suggest making the value of zNear zero or a small number like 0.0001f ?

Comment: @Zarkopafilis you shouldn't set `z-near` to 0 because that can result in some problems when using OpenGL instead use something like 0.1 or 0.00001

Comment: @Zarkopafilis that actually depends on your virtual world and what kind of program you are writing. But for now, any number between 0 and 1 would be okay for you I think.